# run time error Could Not Find Class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, dictionary, google-play-services

I know this question has been asked before in several post, but I've tried everything and none of them solved my problem.
I'm trying  on an app that uses Google Maps v2 API to display a map. the project is compiled without error, but it crashes at run time on the device with this error in LogCat :

```
Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'
```

as I Checked :

1- Last version of Google Service is installed on the device.

2- `google-play-services_lib` project is under same folder as referencing project and it is currectly added to project as Library (as below) :

[image]

3- Google service library is shown under Android dependencies :

4- I decompiled the project's apk and surprisingly in the 'classes' folder I saw `gms` folder without `map` folder and without `SupportMapFragment` class :
[image]

5- I added the lib to build path :

[image]

I would be very grateful if anyone could give an idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the library to the classpath.

For that just right click the library file in the package explorer of eclipse and select add to build path.

Then clean and rebuild and everything should be fine.

Comment: tank you.  right click on which library? in which project? library project or referencing project?

Comment: @MostafaShaeri : You are referring the google play services project right? You can see a google_play_services_lib.jar file inside the libs folder of that project. Copy the same to the libs folder of your application project and then right click on it and select addtobuildpath

Comment: it didn't solved the problem. I copied that file and added it to build path . you can see the picture I just added it in the question.